# How to determine which revision of the SATA is supported by the chipset?

Tags: sata, chipset

I've got a laptop Asus K50IN that, according to the specification, uses NVIDIA MCP75L chipset. How do I determine which revision of the SATA interface is supported by my laptop?

Comment: For most part Sata is forward *and* backward compatible so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I think it's forward compatible in terms of interface, not in terms of supported bandwidth. So, SATA 2.0 HDD will work fine on SATA 1.0 controller, but the bandwidth will be limited by controller. Is that correct?

Comment: @Eldar: Yes, but you won't find an HDD that will suffer from this limit. The maximum transfer rate for SATA 1 is 1.5 Gbit/s -> ~187MB/sec. Only SSDs reach this limit at the moment.

Comment: @Robert: I want to check the SATA revision level exactly because I'm choosing SSD for my laptop and want to see if I would gain in performance with SATA 2 SSD.

Comment: @Eldar: If you are worrying about speed you should consider buying a new notebook.  An old Asus K50IN will limit the speed you get not only by it's SATA port but also by it's processor.

Comment: @Robert: I'm considering that too somewhere in future. Now I'm just looking for the SSD

Answer (score 2):

OK, here is what I've done:

In [CPUZ](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), I've found that my motherboard uses nForce 730i southbridge chipset. Checked  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_chipsets#For_Intel_processors_3), seems that it supports SATA 3Gbit/s. Also, according to the same page, it seems that latest NVidia chipset without 3Gbit/s support was released in 2006, so it should be pretty safe to assume that reasonably modern motherboard with NVidia chipset comes with SATA-II.